# How to use tkinter or Kivy pop-up in my flask server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, tkinter, kivy

I have created a flask app. Now, whenever a new client accesses my webpage I would like to get notified where my server is running. Also, I should allow user manually to access my page.

Here are a few more details.

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

client_list = []

app = Flask(__name__) 
root = Tk()

@app.route('/') 
def hello_world(): 
    # ip_address = request.remote_addr
    # print("Requester IP: " + ip_address)
    # print(client_list)
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/screen') 
def screen():
    if client_list == []:
        if request.remote_addr not in client_list:
            #respose = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("New request!", "Allow new request?")
            respose = input("New connection - yes/no:")
            if respose == 'yes':
                client_list.append(request.remote_addr)
                return render_template("screen.html")
            elif respose == 'no':
                return render_template("noscreen.html")
    elif client_list != []:
        pass

@app.before_request
def find_user():
    if client_list == []:
        if request.remote_addr not in client_list:
            client_list.append(request.remote_addr)
    elif client_list != []:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7000, debug=True)
```

HTML code inside templates folder:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <form action="/screen" method = "POST">
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'Login'/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: You can run the Flask app in separate thread but need to turn off debug mode.  Then run tkinter GUI in main thread.

Comment: You can't. Those libraries expect to have a display. A browser window isn't a display.